# 2 cogwheels with magnets on each cog to create infinite movement?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

I have no experience of physics or what so ever but I was thinking of 2 cogwheels with magnets on each cog to create infinite movement. 
I have no idea on how to try this etc, but I would love to hear your thoughts of it.

[image: cogwheel design]

So basically my idea was that they would never touch eachother so they don't generate heat so there's a little space between them.

Answer (score 0):

Your system would lock up very quickly and cease further movement.

Plainly, the amount of energy and wheel motion gained by the attraction of the magnets must equal the amount of energy and wheel motion lost to repulsion. Furthermore, since the wheels turn they rob the system of even more energy, leaving you with a net loss of energy. Perpetual motion requires a net gain to be useful, and an equilibrium to happen at all.

There's a reason no one has invented perpetual motion yet. Mother Nature always balances her books.